# What is the meaning of this notation in algebraic geometry (from /): $k\left[x_{1},\ldots,x_{r}\right]\mathbf{/\left(f_{1},\ldots,f_{r}\right)}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

I have stumbled on something is apparently a trivial concept, but the difficulty is that I haven't seen this *notation* before.

Here is the fragment of a text from lecture notes:

> Let us call $\rho$ the map from $S$ to $T$.
>   $$
> \rho:\underline{a}=\left(a_{1},\ldots,a_{r}\right)\mapsto\left(x_{1}-a_{1},\ldots,x_{r}-a_{r}\right).
> $$
>   Another way of thinking about it is that $\rho$ maps to a map:
>   $$
> \rho:\underline{a}\mapsto\left\{ \frac{k\left[x_{1},\ldots,x_{r}\right]}{\left(f_{1},\ldots,f_{r}\right)}\overset{x_{i}\mapsto a_{i}}{\longrightarrow}k\right\} 
> $$

[Where $S=\left\{ \underline{a}\in k^{n}\mid f_{1}\left(\underline{a}\right)=\ldots=f_{r}\left(\underline{a}\right)=0\right\}$, $T=\left\{ \textrm{maximal ideals in}\: k\left[x_{1},\ldots x_{r}\right]/\left(f_{1},\ldots,f_{r}\right)\right\}$, and $k$ is an algebraically closed field.]

I understand everything here, except for **this item**:
$$
\frac{k\left[x_{1},\ldots,x_{r}\right]}{\left(f_{1},\ldots,f_{r}\right)}
$$

Normally, this kind of notation is used for quotient of a space by a subspace, for example $A/B$ is a quotient space. However assuming that the above is a quotient space, then I'm not quite sure what kind of subspace is $\left(f_{1},\ldots,f_{r}\right)$. Would it be the vector space with $f_{1},\ldots,f_{r}$ as a basis? A bit confused here.

Comment: $f_i$'s are polynomials and $(f_1,...,f_r)$ denotes the ideal generated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28ring_theory%29#Ideal_generated_by_a_set

Comment: @azarel Okay, so (f1,...,fr) denotes the ideal generated by those polynomials. Thanks.

Comment: @anon Thanks for the advice. I am familiar with the definition of an ideal (and I took Abstract Algebra). I have seen similar notation to (f1,...,fr) on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring , the link you initially posted, so I will look into that.

Comment: @azarel add it as an asnwer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @azarel I agree with leo. It looks to me like this answers my question. So perhaps you can add it as an answer, and I will select it as such.